# Detect key press event that isn't "enter" in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to detect when the user pressed a key that's not the "enter" button.
For example: if the user pressed the "shift" key it will do something.
I have this code but it's not working:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
var keycode = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
if (keycode!= '13) {
  //do somthing
  }
});
```

Comment: Why compare to string when the keycode is a number? Please provide a runnable [mcve] that reproduces problem

Comment: What does not work? Which key are you pressing that doesn't have the expected result?

Comment: Here's some code to demonstrate how to detect a shift button is being pressed, but I can't answer your question because I, or we, don't know what you're trying to do and what doesn't work. However, that aside: https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/pkza2foL/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`KeyboardEvent.keyCode` and `KeyboardEvent.which` are both deprecated (confusing, I know). Use `KeyboardEvent.code` like so:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e){
  if(e.code !== "Enter"){
    // Your code here
  }
});
```

More information at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      document.onkeydown = function(e) {
        if (!e.shiftKey) {
          alert("You have entered a key that was not shift");
        }
      };

    });
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  Please try to enter a key.
</body>

</html>
```